# getting empty array in response res.json(); in nodejs code

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

Why does `res.json` respond with an empty array?
    I want to get all data from collection distributor ,so for that I have 
     created model file and then assigned it to on variable `Distributordata`

**Server file : app.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Distributordata=require('./distributor.model');

var db='mongodb://localhost/Distributordata';

mongoose.connect(db);

var port=8080;

app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.send("happy to be here");  
});

 app.get('/distributor',function(req,res){
// res.send("hi from distributors")
 console.log("getting all distributors");
 Distributordata.find(function(err,distributordata){
      if(err){
        res.send("error has occured");
      }
      else{
          console.log(distributordata);
         res.send(distributordata);
     }
  });
 });

   app.listen(port,function(){
   console.log('app listening on port'+port);
  });
```

**Model file : distributor.model.js**

```
  var mongoose=require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var DistributorSchema=new Schema({
  dname:String,
  daddress: String
  });

  module.exports=mongoose.model('Distributordata',DistributorSchema);
```

output

on cmd:

```
app listening on port8080

  getting all distributors

   [ ]
```

Comment: Is there any data in DB?

Comment: yes,i used mongodb compass for database creation, and created one database named as Distributordata ,and then created one collection named as distributor with record as dname:"Agrostar"  and daddress:"xyz"

Comment: Did you change the standard / default TCP port of MongoDB? Usually it's 27017, and your Mongo URI should be as: `mongodb://localhost:27017/Distributordata`.

Comment: no,i didn't change the default port and also tried with url 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Distributordata' but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've understood your problem is you are creating your collection in mongodb by yourself as the collection name `distributor`. And also as you are not sending any post request so your code will not create any collection automatically in the main database.

But, by default mongoose always creates a collection name by pluralizing the name of the model, in your case this collection name would be **`distributordatas`**. But when, you are trying to get the data from your database, it's getting the collection name as **`distributor`** for this reason it becomes unable to make a connection. But you can keep this using **force** naming convention for collection as like you want.

In your **distributor.model.js** file change this line of code to this one:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Distributordata', DistributorSchema, 'distributor');
```

Hopefully, it'll solve your problem. For more reference check this out https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection

Comment: thanks for detail explanation,                                                                                          i changed my code line as you said,but it doesn't worked, then as you explained that i am creating collection and using it for getting data....rather mongodb create default collection....,so i have drop my collection and used default one created by mongodb and used post request for adding records and then get request for getting those records.....and finally i am getting object with records... !!!!!!!!!!thank you

Comment: Welcome. But that line should've worked. Anyways your problem is solved. Would you mind marking the answer as the correct answer? Thanks